# WINDOWS Server 2016 RDS Rights migration

Tags: windows, permissions, rds

We installed the RDS role on a windows server 2016 using an admin account on the server.

when we connect via another account (also admin), we cannot see the same view on the RDS (with the message in PJ).

[image: A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist in the server pool. To create a deployment, run the Add Roles and Features Wizard and select the Remote Desktop Services installation option.]

Do you have any idea how to manage RDS roles?

thank you in advance